# I can see the directory in the python sys.path yet I get an error when I try to import the library?

Tags: python, windows, import, path

My guess is I am missing something very basic and obvious which some one can point out to me.

The below screen capture of a short command-line session shows the following:

I can see the `pysal` directory exists in the `sys.path` yet I get an ImportError when I try to `import pysal`?

[image]

Comment: And what is the contents of `C:\Users\Max\Documents\Pysal`?

Comment: some directories : \core \esda \examples and a file __init__.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python imports packages and modules *within* the entries in `sys.path`, not the entries themselves. This means that either `C:\Users\Max\Documents\pysal\pysal.py` or `C:\Users\Max\Documents\pysal\pysal\__init__.py` would have to exist in order to be imported.